# application on system startup

Tags: mysql, delphi, windows-xp, startup

I have an application built in `Delphi` and it accesses `MySQL` database using `MyDAC components`and `Windows XP` O.S. .

I want this application to run on `System Startup`,so I added the `Application shortcut` to the `Startup` folder also added a `Registry key` .

But when I start my system ,first an Microsoft error message pops up

```
 Myapplication.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.
```

and asks for error reporting.
After this another error from the application comes up

```
 Exception EMyError in module MyApplication.exe
 Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'(10061)
 Socket error on connect.
```

how do I overcome this?

any help appreciated

Comment: The app will start at user logon rather than system start. If you really want system start then you need a service.

Comment: @david its a single user system

Comment: Then the app will start when that single user logs on and not at system start. You probably want logon but the terminology in the Q was a little slack.

Comment: There are several ways to run an application at startup. Services are just one way. Other ways are the task scheduler, the Run keys in the registry and some others. The one to choose depends on what the applications does and how it works. Since Vista it is hard to run an interactive application as a service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some hints:

- You should better implements a *Windows Service* so that the application will start even before the first user log into the system;
- Services may be started before the network or the DB is ready, so you get this `EMyError` exception - in this case, use `Sleep(5000)` to wait for 5 seconds, then retry until the connection will take place.

A typical code, using a service, may be:

```
procedure TMyService.Execute;
var retry: boolean;
begin
  retry := true;
  repeat
    try
      ConnectToDatabase;
      retry := false; // connection success
    except
      on E: EMyError do 
        sleep(5000); // wait 5 seconds and retry
    end;
    if Terminated then
      exit; // avoid endless loop
  until not retry;
  // ... now you are connected and you can continue
```

Comment: If his application has a UI a service may be the wrong choice. Also there's no need to wait for another service to start. Services have depencebcies, you may set that your service depends on another (i.e. the MySQL one), and Windows will ensure the services your one depends on are started before yours. Of course it works well if the other service waits to be fully initialized before returning control to the service manager.
Also your code will hang the application if it can't connect. I'd add a way to terminate it anyway.

Comment: is there any way to start the `MySQL` service before my aplication starts

Comment: @ldsandon Setting dependencies is another solution, but it's a bit more technical. And as you stated, it depends on the main service implementation - for instance, it won't work with Oracle - but I do not know with MySQL. So the loop+Sleep solution is a working one. About the endless loop, you're perfectly right - so I've updated the code.

Comment: @Shirish11 As ldsandon wrote, you can set the dependency, but the service may be started, but not yet running (it may takes some times to have all initialization processed). You may have another way of checking for MySQL to be started and initialized (check MyDAC component), but the raised exception by the loop+sleep solution is not a big concern IMHO.

Comment: @ldsandon You are perfectly right about UI interaction - this is not permitted any more since Vista for a service to access the desktop, if I remember well (for trolling security reasons). But according to a layered architecture, it does make sense that the service won't better have any direct UI interaction.

Comment: I had a similar problem with hMailServer and MySQL and adding a dependency worked. Anyway error checking and error-proof code is always better.
Dependency are also useful because they will start any needed service anyway, and will warn the user when attempting to stop a service that dependents service will be stopped as well, ensuring they stay in a consistent state. Technically, it's just a string entry in the registry.
Oracle has the listener to hand-off connections to the database instance, which makes everything more complex, and the service just bootstrap the real instance process.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement a try .. except loop for your connect. If it fails, it should wait some time and try again. Most likely your app starts earlier and/or faster than your mysql instance.

Comment: how long to wait,different systems will have different startup times and will depend on the resources available.

Comment: Perhaps you can get process information on the mysql process to determine whether it is already running. Otherwise, start with a 10 sec wait, and see if it is too long/short and change it.

Comment: How about a configurable value in the registry, inifile or whereever?

Comment: Just retry connection in a loop. You'll never be able to predict ahead of time how long to wait.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan A sleep() as suggested by pritaeas in case of failure does make sense to avoid burning the CPU for nothing.

Comment: @arnaud who said anything about a busy loop?